# Nesting duplicate variables when joining with dplyr in R

Tags: r, join, merge, dplyr, tidyr

I'm joining data frames (tibbles) that have duplicated columns that I **do not** want to join. Example below is what I would usually do (joining by `i`, but not `a` or `b`):

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- tibble(i = letters[1:3], a = 1:3,   b = 4:6)
df2 <- tibble(i = letters[1:3], a = 11:13, b = 14:16)

d <- full_join(df1, df2, by ="i")
d
#> # A tibble: 3 × 5
#>       i   a.x   b.x   a.y   b.y
#>   <chr> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     a     1     4    11    14
#> 2     b     2     5    12    15
#> 3     c     3     6    13    16
```

I want these duplicated variables to be returned as nested lists such as the output created below:

```
tibble(
  i = letters[1:3],
  a = list(c(1, 11), c(2, 12), c(3, 13)),
  b = list(c(4, 14), c(5, 15), c(6, 16))
)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>       i         a         b
#>   <chr>    <list>    <list>
#> 1     a <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]>
#> 2     b <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]>
#> 3     c <dbl [2]> <dbl [2]>
```

Is there a simple way to do such a thing?

Aside, I've been playing around (unsuccessfully) with various stringr and tidyr methods. Here's an example that throws an error:

```
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)

# Find any variables with .x or .y
dup_var <- d %>% select(matches("\\.[xy]")) %>% names()

# Condense to the stems (original names) of these variables
dup_var_stems <- dup_var %>% str_replace("(\\.[x|y])+", "") %>% unique()

# For each stem, try to nest relevant data into a single variable
for (stem in dup_var_stems) {
  d <- d %>% nest_(key_col = stem, nest_cols = names(d)[str_detect(names(d), paste0(stem, "[$|\\.]"))])
}
```

UPDATE

After answers from @Sotos and @conor, I'll mention that the solution needs to generalise to multiple joining and duplicated columns over many data frames. Below is an example where joining is done on five data frames by two columns (`i` and `j`). This creates five duplicated versions of columns `a` and `b`, with plenty of unique columns too `c`:`g`. One problem is that duplicating over so many data frames results in duplicated versions having no suffix, `.x`, `.x.x`, and so on. So simple regex match for `.x|.y` will miss the no-suffix version of the column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)


id_cols <- tibble(i = c("x", "x", "y", "y"),
                  j = c(1, 2, 1, 2))

df1 <- id_cols %>% cbind(tibble(a = 1:4, b = 5:8, c = 21:24))
df2 <- id_cols %>% cbind(tibble(a = 2:5, b = 6:9, d = 31:34))
df3 <- id_cols %>% cbind(tibble(a = 2:5, b = 6:9, e = 31:34))
df4 <- id_cols %>% cbind(tibble(a = 2:5, b = 6:9, f = 31:34))
df5 <- id_cols %>% cbind(tibble(a = 2:5, b = 6:9, g = 31:34))
datalist <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)

d <- reduce(datalist, full_join, by = c("i", "j"))
d
#>   i j a.x b.x  c a.y b.y  d a.x.x b.x.x  e a.y.y b.y.y  f a b  g
#> 1 x 1   1   5 21   2   6 31     2     6 31     2     6 31 2 6 31
#> 2 x 2   2   6 22   3   7 32     3     7 32     3     7 32 3 7 32
#> 3 y 1   3   7 23   4   8 33     4     8 33     4     8 33 4 8 33
#> 4 y 2   4   8 24   5   9 34     5     9 34     5     9 34 5 9 34
```

Comment: I think the error you're getting in your attempt is a little odd. It should be ok to `nest` tibbles that already have a nested column. You might want to report that.

Comment: Thanks @Axeman. I've reduced it down to excluding list variables from a `nest()`. I've posted this as an issue on the tidyr repository https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/issues/249

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one attempt,

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

melt(d, id.vars = 'i') %>% 
   group_by(a = sub('\\..*', '', variable), i) %>% 
   summarise(new = list(value)) %>% 
   spread(a, new)

# A tibble: 3 × 3
#      i         a         b
#* <chr>    <list>    <list>
#1     a <int [2]> <int [2]>
#2     b <int [2]> <int [2]>
#3     c <int [2]> <int [2]>

#With structure
Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ i: chr  "a" "b" "c"
 $ a:List of 3
  ..$ : int  1 11
  ..$ : int  2 12
  ..$ : int  3 13
 $ b:List of 3
  ..$ : int  4 14
  ..$ : int  5 15
  ..$ : int  6 16

#Or via reshape2 package

library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)

d1 <- melt(d, id.vars = 'i') %>% 
         group_by(a = sub('\\..*', '', variable), i) %>% 
         summarise(new = list(value))

d2 <- dcast(d1, i ~ a, value.var = 'new')
#d2
#  i     a     b
#1 a 1, 11 4, 14
#2 b 2, 12 5, 15
#3 c 3, 13 6, 16

#with structure:
str(d2)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ i: chr  "a" "b" "c"
 $ a:List of 3
  ..$ : int  1 11
  ..$ : int  2 12
  ..$ : int  3 13
 $ b:List of 3
  ..$ : int  4 14
  ..$ : int  5 15
  ..$ : int  6 16
```

**EDIT**

To follow your thought,

```
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

df <- melt(d, id.vars = c(names(d)[!grepl('a|b', names(d))]))

dots <- names(df)[!grepl('value', names(df))] %>% map(as.symbol)

df %>% mutate(variable = sub('\\..*', '', variable)) %>%
     group_by_(.dots = dots) %>%
     summarise(new = list(value)) %>%
     spread(variable, new) %>%
     ungroup()
# A tibble: 4 × 9
#      i     j     c     d     e     f     g         a         b
#* <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>    <list>    <list>
#1     x     1    21    31    31    31    31 <int [5]> <int [5]>
#2     x     2    22    32    32    32    32 <int [5]> <int [5]>
#3     y     1    23    33    33    33    33 <int [5]> <int [5]>
#4     y     2    24    34    34    34    34 <int [5]> <int [5]>
```

Comment: Thanks @Sotos. This is a nice solution to the example I presented (and I've upvoted). However, the solution needs to be more generalisable than the example makes out (this is my fault - I was trying to be too concise). I've included an update in the question to show this. Based on your idea, I developed a solution that I'll put as an answer. Perhaps you can improve on it?

Comment: Thanks again, @Sotos. This gets at the heart of the problem now. The solution I posted is more generalisable at the initial `melt`/`gather` stage (i.e., to handle variables other than `a` or `b`), so I will leave it up for others. However, the rest (which is more important) is based on your idea.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly more verbose than `Sotos` answer, but this will also work.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

d_tidy <- gather(d, col, val, a.x:b.y, -i)
d_tidy$col <- str_replace(d_tidy$col, ".x|.y", "")
d_tidy %>% group_by(i, col) %>% 
    summarise(val = list(val)) %>% 
    spread(col, val) %>% 
    ungroup()

       i         a         b
  <fctr>    <list>    <list>
1      a <int [2]> <int [2]>
2      b <int [2]> <int [2]>
3      c <int [2]> <int [2]>
```

If you want to use `nest` to create `lists` of `dataframes` you can do this instead

```
d_tidy <- gather(d, col, val, a.x:b.y, -i)
d_tidy$col <- str_replace(d_tidy$col, ".x|.y", "")
d_tidy %>% 
    group_by(i, col) %>% 
    nest(col) %>% 
    spread(col, data)

       i              a              b
  <fctr>         <list>         <list>
1      a <tbl_df [2,0]> <tbl_df [2,0]>
2      b <tbl_df [2,0]> <tbl_df [2,0]>
3      c <tbl_df [2,0]> <tbl_df [2,0]>
```

Comment: Thanks @conor. It's on point for specific case, but I need something more general. I've updated question (and given separate solution to demonstrate).

Comment: no problem @SimonJackson. I am glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

After updating the question, I arrived at the following based on the `melt()` solution provided by @Sotos (so please upvote that solution too if you think this works).

The following is a function that should take a data frame like the ones described, and nest duplicated columns. See comments throughout for explanation.

Create the problem data frame:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

id_cols <- tibble(i = c("x", "x", "y", "y"),
                  j = c(1, 2, 1, 2))

df1 <- id_cols %>% cbind(tibble(a = 1:4, b = 5:8, c = 21:24))
df2 <- id_cols %>% cbind(tibble(a = 2:5, b = 6:9, d = 31:34))
df3 <- id_cols %>% cbind(tibble(a = 2:5, b = 6:9, e = 31:34))
df4 <- id_cols %>% cbind(tibble(a = 2:5, b = 6:9, f = 31:34))
df5 <- id_cols %>% cbind(tibble(a = 2:5, b = 6:9, g = 31:34))
datalist <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4, df5)

d <- reduce(datalist, full_join, by = c("i", "j"))
d
#>   i j a.x b.x  c a.y b.y  d a.x.x b.x.x  e a.y.y b.y.y  f a b  g
#> 1 x 1   1   5 21   2   6 31     2     6 31     2     6 31 2 6 31
#> 2 x 2   2   6 22   3   7 32     3     7 32     3     7 32 3 7 32
#> 3 y 1   3   7 23   4   8 33     4     8 33     4     8 33 4 8 33
#> 4 y 2   4   8 24   5   9 34     5     9 34     5     9 34 5 9 34
```

Create function `nest_duplicates()`

```
# Function to nest duplicated columns after joining multiple data frames
#
# Args:
#   df Data frame of joined data frames with duplicated columns.
#   suffixes Character string to match suffixes. E.g., the default "\\.[xy]"
#            finds any columns ending with .x or .y
#
# Depends on: dplyr, tidyr, purrr, stringr
nest_duplicated <- function(df, suffixes = "\\.[xy]") {

  # Search string to match any duplicated variables
  search_string <- df %>%
    dplyr::select(dplyr::matches(suffixes)) %>%
    names() %>%
    stringr::str_replace_all(suffixes, "") %>%
    unique() %>%
    stringr::str_c(collapse = "|") %>%
    stringr::str_c("(", ., ")($|", suffixes, ")")

  # Gather duplicated variables and convert names to stems
  df <- df %>%
    tidyr::gather(variable, value, dplyr::matches(search_string)) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(variable = stringr::str_replace_all(variable, suffixes, ""))

  # Group by all columns except value to convert duplicated rows into list, then
  # spread by variable (var)
  dots <- names(df)[!stringr::str_detect(names(df), "value")] %>% purrr::map(as.symbol)
  df %>%
    dplyr::group_by_(.dots = dots) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(new = list(value)) %>%
    tidyr::spread(variable, new) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup()
}
```

Apply `nest_duplicates()`:

```
nest_duplicated(d)

#> # A tibble: 4 × 9
#>       i     j     c     d     e     f     g         a         b
#> * <chr> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>    <list>    <list>
#> 1     x     1    21    31    31    31    31 <int [5]> <int [5]>
#> 2     x     2    22    32    32    32    32 <int [5]> <int [5]>
#> 3     y     1    23    33    33    33    33 <int [5]> <int [5]>
#> 4     y     2    24    34    34    34    34 <int [5]> <int [5]>
```

Updates/improvements welcome!